# Linking error with soci-postgresql

Tags: c++, postgresql, soci

I followed following steps to build soci with postgresql and build my application with soci.

1) Checkout code from git in to directory /home/sujith/soci/src

```
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/src$ pwd
/home/sujith/soci/src
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/src$ ls
appveyor.yml  AUTHORS  bin  CHANGES  cmake  CMakeLists.txt  CTestConfig.cmake  docs  include  languages  LICENSE_1_0.txt  README.md  src  tests  TODO  Vagrantfile  www
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/src$
```

2) cmake done

```
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/build$ pwd
/home/sujith/soci/build
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/build$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DWITH_POSTGRESQL=ON ../src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.2.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for __i386__
-- Looking for __i386__ - not found
-- Looking for __x86_64__
-- Looking for __x86_64__ - found
-- Looking for __arm__
-- Looking for __arm__ - not found
-- Configuring SOCI: 
-- SOCI_VERSION                             = 4.0.0 
-- SOCI_ABI_VERSION                         = 4.0 
-- SOCI_SHARED                              = ON 
-- SOCI_STATIC                              = ON 
-- SOCI_TESTS                               = ON 
-- SOCI_CXX_C11                             = OFF 
-- Looking for SOCI dependencies: 
-- Threads: 
-- CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT                   = -lpthread 
-- Boost: 
-- Boost_RELEASE_VERSION                    = 1.60.0 
-- Boost_INCLUDE_DIR                        = /usr/local/include 
-- Boost_LIBRARIES                          = /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so 
-- MySQL: 
-- Performing Test HAVE_MYSQL_OPT_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_MYSQL_OPT_EMBEDDED_CONNECTION - Failed
-- MySQL not found.
-- MySQL Embedded not found.
-- WARNING: 
-- MySQL not found, some libraries or features will be disabled. 
-- See the documentation for MySQL or manually set these variables: 
-- MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR                        = MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND 
-- MYSQL_LIBRARIES                          = MYSQL_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND 
-- ODBC: 
-- Looking for include files windows.h, sqlext.h
-- Looking for include files windows.h, sqlext.h - not found
-- WARNING: 
-- ODBC not found, some libraries or features will be disabled. 
-- See the documentation for ODBC or manually set these variables: 
-- ODBC_INCLUDE_DIR                         = ODBC_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND 
-- ODBC_LIBRARIES                           = ODBC_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND 
-- Oracle: 
-- ORACLE_HOME=
-- WARNING: 
-- Oracle not found, some libraries or features will be disabled. 
-- See the documentation for Oracle or manually set these variables: 
-- ORACLE_INCLUDE_DIR                       = ORACLE_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND 
-- ORACLE_LIBRARIES                         = ORACLE_OCI_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND ORACLE_OCCI_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND ORACLE_NNZ_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND 
-- PostgreSQL: 
-- POSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIR                   = /usr/include/postgresql 
-- POSTGRESQL_LIBRARIES                     = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so 
-- POSTGRESQL_VERSION                       = 9.4.6 
-- SQLite3: 
-- WARNING: 
-- SQLite3 not found, some libraries or features will be disabled. 
-- See the documentation for SQLite3 or manually set these variables: 
-- SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR                      = SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND 
-- SQLITE3_LIBRARIES                        = SQLITE3_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND 
-- Firebird: 
-- SOCI_FIREBIRD_EMBEDDED                   = OFF 
-- WARNING: 
-- Firebird not found, some libraries or features will be disabled. 
-- See the documentation for Firebird or manually set these variables: 
-- FIREBIRD_INCLUDE_DIR                     = FIREBIRD_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND 
-- FIREBIRD_LIBRARIES                       = FIREBIRD_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND 
-- FIREBIRD_VERSION                         =  
-- DB2: 
-- WARNING: 
-- DB2 not found, some libraries or features will be disabled. 
-- See the documentation for DB2 or manually set these variables: 
-- DB2_INCLUDE_DIR                          = DB2_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND 
-- DB2_LIBRARIES                            = DB2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND 
-- Configuring SOCI core library: 
-- SOCI_CORE_TARGET                         = soci_core 
-- SOCI_CORE_TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME             = soci_core 
-- SOCI_CORE_DEPS_LIBS                      = -lpthread /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so 
-- SOCI_CORE_INCLUDE_DIRS                   = /usr/local/include /home/sujith/soci/build /home/sujith/soci/src/include /home/sujith/soci/build/include /home/sujith/soci/src/include/private /home/sujith/soci/build/src/core 
-- WITH_BOOST                               = ON 
-- COMPILE_DEFINITIONS                      = SOCI_ABI_VERSION="4.0" HAVE_DL=1 BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB SOCI_LIB_PREFIX="libsoci_" SOCI_LIB_SUFFIX=".so" SOCI_DEBUG_POSTFIX="" 
-- 
-- Configuring SOCI backend libraries: 
-- MySQL not found.
-- MySQL Embedded not found.
-- ORACLE_HOME=
-- Empty - SOCI backend skeleton for new backends development 
-- SOCI_EMPTY                               = ON 
-- SOCI_EMPTY_TARGET                        = soci_empty 
-- SOCI_EMPTY_OUTPUT_NAME                   = soci_empty 
-- SOCI_EMPTY_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS           = SOCI_ABI_VERSION="4.0" HAVE_DL=1 BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB 
-- SOCI_EMPTY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES           = /usr/local/include /home/sujith/soci/build /home/sujith/soci/src/include /home/sujith/soci/build/include /home/sujith/soci/src/include/private /home/sujith/soci/src/include/private 
-- PostgreSQL - SOCI backend for PostgreSQL 
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL                          = ON 
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_TARGET                   = soci_postgresql 
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_OUTPUT_NAME              = soci_postgresql 
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS      = SOCI_ABI_VERSION="4.0" HAVE_DL=1 BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB 
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES      = /usr/local/include /home/sujith/soci/build /home/sujith/soci/src/include /home/sujith/soci/build/include /home/sujith/soci/src/include/private /home/sujith/soci/src/include/private /usr/include/postgresql 
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_NOPARAMS                 = OFF 
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_NOBINDBYNAME             = OFF 
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_NOPREPARE                = OFF 
-- 
-- Configuring SOCI tests: 
-- SOCI_EMPTY_TEST_CONNSTR                  = dummy
-- MS Access test disabled on non-Windows platform
-- SOCI_POSTGRESQL_TEST_CONNSTR             = dbname=soci_test
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/sujith/soci/build
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/build$
```

3) make
4) Build my code

```
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/test$ pwd
/home/sujith/soci/test
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/test$ cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <soci/soci.h>
#include <soci/postgresql/soci-postgresql.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(const int argc, const char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        soci::session sql;
        sql.open(soci::postgresql, "service=exd16 user=exd16 password=exd16");
        return 0;
    }
    catch (exception const &e)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR : " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
};

sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/test$ cat c
g++ -ggdb -I /home/sujith/soci/src/include -I /home/sujith/soci/build/include -I /usr/include/postgresql -L /home/sujith/soci/build/lib -L /usr/local/pgsql/lib -lsoci_core -lsoci_empty -lpq -lsoci_postgresql -lsoci_empty  main.cpp
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/test$ ./c
/tmp/ccLp881A.o: In function `main':
/home/sujith/soci/test/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `soci::session::session()'
/home/sujith/soci/test/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `soci::postgresql'
/home/sujith/soci/test/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `soci::session::open(soci::backend_factory const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/sujith/soci/test/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `soci::session::~session()'
/home/sujith/soci/test/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `soci::session::~session()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
sujith@sujith-VirtualBox:~/soci/test$
```

Please help me in finding the linking error.

According to my understanding I have linked all the required libraries.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. If you linked with all the required libraries, you would not've gotten the link error.

Comment: Not working even with this : c++ -pedantic -Werror -Wno-error=parentheses -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wfloat-equal -Wredundant-decls -Wno-long-long -std=gnu++98  -Wno-variadic-macros -rdynamic -lpthread -ldl /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so -I /home/sujith/soci/src/include -I /home/sujith/soci/build/include -I /usr/include/postgresql -L /home/sujith/soci/build/lib -L /usr/local/pgsql/lib -lpq /home/sujith/soci/build/lib/libsoci_core.so.4.0.0 /home/sujith/soci/build/lib/libsoci_empty.so.4.0.0 /home/sujith/soci/build/lib/libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0  main.cpp

Comment: libsoci_core.so.4.0.0, libsoci_empty.so.4.0.0, libsoci_postgresql.so.4.0.0 all linked

Comment: When using SOCI with PostgreSQL you also need to link in libpq.

Comment: @sujithGunawardhane I think that the problem is compilation command - linker options should be after code, I mean that `-I /usr/include/postgresql -L /home/sujith/soci/build/lib -L /usr/local/pgsql/lib -lsoci_core -lsoci_empty -lpq -lsoci_postgresql -lsoci_empty ` should be after `main.cpp`